# How can I connect to localhost from another computer?

Tags: android, ip, localhost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connect to localhost from another computer](https://superuser.com/questions/308451/connect-to-localhost-from-another-computer)

Hi all I'm trying to access a database that is hosted in a laptop localhost from my android device which is both connected to the same network.

The localhost project is running at www.localhost:8000/

I've entered the ip: 192.168.1.1 (of my laptop connection) to my phone browser and i was able to see the root folder of my project. However when i attempted to run it at 192.168.1.1:8000/ , I was not able to access anything and the web browser returned "Webpage not available".

So the issue now is that I can access the root folder using my android device but I cannot access the "localhost server" of my laptop. Is there anyway I can solve it ? THanks !

Comment: I realize that you need to connect to your database for your development work, but this isn't really a programming question. It's a question about configuring your database server, so it would probably get a much better response on serverfault or superuser.

Comment: Hi Flimzy ! Thanks for your answer. Yea cos I found some similar questions on Stackoverflow and hence went ahead to post the question. I wanted to try and have my other devices connect to the localhost database to try out the connection :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because the device has two IP addresses (192.168.1.1 and 127.0.0.1, aka localhost or loopback), doesn't mean the server is listening on both addresses.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your answer. So are you saying i'd need to go into the etc/hosts file to comment off one of the ip for it to work ?

Comment: No - you need to configure your database to accept connections from sources other than localhost. You don't specify the database product so that's as far as I can take you. But basically databases generally "bind" to one or more available IP addresses and accept connections from them. This binding is specified in a configuration file or GUI. You need to tell your DB to bind to 192.168.1.1. Note there are security implications for doing this that you should understand. DB's bind by default to localhost for a reason.