# How to get to my computer's localhost from other devices

Tags: networking, localhost

**BACKSTORY:**

One day, I looked up my private IP address in the URL because I was bored. What I found out was that it led to my localhost (the XAMPP dashboard), so I tried to type in my IP address from another device, but my computer either blocked the connection or didn't respond.

**WHY THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE:**

In the other [question](https://superuser.com/questions/308451/connect-to-localhost-from-another-computer), OP was able to access localhost from other devices, but he/she/other wanted to access a database, but I just can't access localhost from another device.

**QUESTION**:

So, how do I get my computer to respond/not block the other device?

**EDIT - INFO:**

IP: 192.168.56.1, Operating System: Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: It may help us understand if you put the IP addresses in your question, and maybe tell us the what this url you are mentioning is. As for what I think you are asking, check out which nic the process/port is bound to. you can do this on linux (as root) with `netstat -ntlup`  or in windows powershell (as admin) `netstat -abno | findstr LISTENING`, and then finding the XAMPP process that you are seeing. if its Local Address is `127.0.0.1`, it can only be accessed by the local machine. you will have to look at XAMPP configuration options to make it remotely accessible.

Comment: this thread may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to

Comment: "In the other question" What other question? There are 383k questions on [su] alone ...

Comment: Edited it so that it includes the link

Comment: So when you run the powershell command I posted, do you see an httpd process on the port in your url (or port 80 if there is no port on the url)? what is its local address?

Comment: It runs, doesn't output anything, then ends

Comment: you need to run the shell as admin.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1i0q1WDpjom8m_v1TaAAs6uyUdtbj7BXCl4NEnQTXXa4/edit Is where the output is

Comment: And does the url you are looking at specify a port number? for instance in `https://127.0.0.1:1234`   the port is 1234.

Comment: @FrankThomas   Port number 8080

Comment: then your port is bound correctly (its listening on 0.0.0.0), and the service should be reachable on any IP assigned on any nic on the system. that means that your issue is probably firewall configuration. What firewall/av system do you use? It is still possible that the application is configured specially to not respond to remote requests, but it would be unusual to do that when binding to 0.0.0.0 (you would bind to 127.0.0.1, so no other system could reach it).

Answer (score 0):

### Create an Inbound Port Rule

In Windows 10 you need to specify each port that's being opened.

You can follow this detailed instructions to do so:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/windows-firewall/create-an-inbound-port-rule

### Use Dynamic DNS Services

Then, if you want to access the computer from outside the LAN (for anyone with Internet access) you can use Dynamic DNS's.

There's even a supposedly Free service [in here](https://www.noip.com/free), you should see the video. This type of software has been around for decades already but have never used such, I prefer to use static IP's for my servers.

Comment: For the dynamic DNS part, could everybody just type the IP address?

Comment: Also, sorry to say, but the answer does not work.

Comment: Note that if you want to access the server from outside your LAN, then you must forward ports on your router.

Comment: @milkyway90 to your question, yes... When all required ports are open.

Comment: @MilkyWay90 To resolve your problem, maybe you should check for instructions specifically for XAMPP under Windows 10, like this 2: https://pureinfotech.com/install-xampp-windows-10/ and https://www.cloudways.com/blog/configure-virtual-host-on-windows-10-for-wordpress/